# Convert DB Columns to be appropriated for MYSQL import

Tags: mysql, database, excel, database-design

I am trying to convert DB columns to the following manner:

Here is my original DB:

[image]

Here in the first column I have the id and them the files for each ID.

I would like to covert this order in a format friendly for Mysql DB to be imported like the following:

[image]

Where in the second file each id is on his row with it's file. My question is there a way to make this with Excel or on the import to the MYSQL DB. Any help will be very welcome. Thanks in advance.  I don't know what is the exact name of this operation to search for help online how it can be achieved so this is why I am posting this question here.

Comment: Can you use python? I can write you a code that will convert it to your format easily.

Comment: I can use php, don't have much knowledge of python.

Comment: That is a pretty wrong-headed original db. Read about pivoting.